# Tikz plots distorted mark

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\begin{document}
  \tikz{\draw (0,0) -- plot[mark=o] (0.5,0) -- (1,0);}
\end{document}
```

It seems that the mark is not smoothly drawn:

[image: Output]

Using the `smooth` option does not have any effects since the interpolation algorithm only affects line drawing; here the distortion occurs on the marks. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Could you please add a Minimal Working Example (MWE), that is a complete code that demonstrates the problem (incl any packages that are read).

Comment: @rkmylo maybe you could add `\pgfuseplotmark{o}` to your example, to show the difference (which i can see too).

Comment: @zeroth you are wrong. zooming in does not remove the distortion. I have made a similar question [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/line-plot-example/#c17372). In the link I pointed, observe the difference between the triangle mark in the actual plot and the corresponding triangle mark shown in the legend. Both, have been drawn using tikz/pgf and the one is smoothly drawn, while the other is not.

Comment: @zeroth the image shown in my post is from TexShop viewer with 1000% zoom. I also tried Adobe Reader with 6400% zoom and the difference is still obvious.

Comment: @zeroth to make the difference as clear as possible, take a look at these two pictures [1](http://imgur.com/5YYTB,00xHY#0) [2](http://imgur.com/5YYTB,00xHY#1). Both, are shown in Adobe Reader with 6400% zoom.

Comment: @rkmylo, I dont have a definite answer, other than it is not so easy to fix. I will delete my comments as they do not provide any insight. Thanks for your patience with me! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax for plotting a point: `plot (0.5,0)` is assumed to be a function, so it's evaluated several times (depending on the `sample` number), and several instances of your point are plotted on top of each other. Fixes: Either set `samples at=1` to make sure your point is only plotted once, or use the official syntax for plotting points, which is `plot coordinates {(0.5,0)}`

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\begin{document}
  \tikz{\draw (0,0) -- plot[mark=o] (0.5,0) -- (1,0);}
  \tikz{\draw (0,0) -- plot[samples at={1}, mark=o] (0.5,0) -- (1,0);}
  \tikz{\draw (0,0) -- plot[mark=o] coordinates {(0.5,0)} -- (1,0);}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jake thank you very much. The `coordinates` keyword indeed solves the problem (enables anti-aliasing).